# Failed opening the RDB file root (in server root dir /etc/crontabs) for saving: Permission denied

Tags: redis, docker-compose

I got this error when deploy docker-compose with redis

```
220:C 23 Jul 2020 11:21:59.091 # Failed opening the RDB file root (in server root dir /etc/crontabs) for saving: Permission denied
```

1:M 23 Jul 2020 11:21:59.191 # Background saving error

My docker-compose file is

```
version: '3'
services:
 main-otp-api:
  image: "mainotp/api:latest"
  ports:
   - "5000:5000"
 redis:
  image: "redis:alpine"
  ports:
   - "6379:6379"
  volumes: 
   - /home/mainotp-server/redis:/data
   - /home/mainotp-server/conf/redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Sounds like your dockerized server has been hacked - is it open to the interwebz?

Comment: Why do you think it was hacked? I dont know why still do not have error after i restart service redis

Comment: Because the default location for RDB isn't that path, and that path is usually used by corn for running scheduled processes

Comment: yep, i try to delete user account, and try to re deploy. it's worked.

Answer (score 1):

So for anyone experiencing this problem, here is a fix that will sort you out.
Access the redis container shell with an interactive terminal

```
docker exec -it redis-container-id /bin/bash
```

Output will look something like this `root@c4da3f40b65f:/data#`.
Run `cd` to go the root of the file directory.  Output `root@c4da3f40b65f:~#`.

At the root change the file permissions for `/data` and `/etc`

Run

```
chmod 777 -R /data  // for the data directory
chmod 777 -R /etc   // for etc folder.
```

You do not have to worry about the user group issues.

Comment: but this will break all security voids.
your system became vulnerable

Comment: @Mohanraj about security, i would recommend implementing redis security measures outlined in their docs. https://redis.io/docs/manual/security/.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to `chown -R redis:redis /etc/crontabs`, from inside the running Redis container. To figure out which user to put there, run `top` and notice who is the user for `redis-server`.